# No matchers inside InteractionBuilder. How to specify Kakao view UI-element using its classes?

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing

I use Espresso framework for my UI-tests and now i want to use Kakao. 
I have a MainPage with some view and that view can be found in next way:

```
class MainPage() {
    val screenTitle =
        CoreMatchers.allOf(
            withText("Main page"),
            withParent(withId(R.id.mediaViewToolbar))
        )
}
```

In Espresso test case these lines work without problems

```
val mainPage = MainPage()
onView(mainPage.screenTitle).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

Then I tried to rewrite this MainPage with its view in Kakao style:

```
class MainScreen : Screen<MainScreen>() {
    // here i faced a problem
    val screenTitle = KBaseView<Matcher<View>>{    // this 2-nd line* is refferenced by error 
        CoreMatchers.allOf(
            ViewMatchers.withText("Main page"),
            ViewMatchers.withParent(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.mediaViewToolbar))
        )
    }
}
```

And if try to write test case in Kakao style

```
val mainScreen = MainScreen()
mainScreen {
    screenTitle {
        isDisplayed()
    }
}
```

Then i get next error:

```
E/TestRunner: failed: should_check_main_page(com.project.online.MainScreenKaspressoTest)
    ----- begin exception -----
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No matchers inside InteractionBuilder
        at com.agoda.kakao.common.builders.ViewBuilder.getViewInteractionDelegate(ViewBuilder.kt:395)
        at com.agoda.kakao.common.views.KBaseView.<init>(KBaseView.kt:42)
        at com.project.online.MainScreen.<init>(MainScreen.kt:2)* - 2-nd line
```

I understand that i specify `screenTitle` in MainScreen by wrong way, but how is correct?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing similar issue while trying to use kaspresso (a wrapper built on top of Kakao)
The idea is more or less same that's used in previous answer, but you have to add `withMatcher()` function before using any custom matcher.
So in your case, it will become something like

```
val screenTitle = KTextView {
  withText("Main page")
  withMatcher { //your custom matcher }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kakao is relying on its `ViewBuilder` DSL to build necessary matchers for the view.
Here's how you should define it:

```
val screenTitle = KTextView {
  withText("Main page")
  withParent { withId(R.id.mediaViewToolbar) }
}
```

Kakao will automatically applies `allOf()` on all invoked matchers.